# Running script on my page is making its content disappear

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am working on sharepoint online.
I am trying to display my current sharepoint username using script and i am able to display it.
While my page is loading the content is shown but as soon as its gets loaded the content in my body disappears  and a blank white page with the current username gets shown.
I already searched net it tells to close your script tags properly and i checked they are already closed properly.

The script is in my header tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var scriptbase = "https://MySiteUrl" + "/_layouts/15/";

 $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
               function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", GetLoginName);
          });
      });
       });


function GetLoginName()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();  
var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();  
currentUser.retrieve();
context.load(web);
context.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){ //On success function
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    var loginName = userObject.get_title();
    document.write(loginName);

 },
 function(){ //On fail function
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
 );
}
</script>
```

In my body right now i am simply displaying hello which disappears.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>hello</div>        
</form> 
</body>
```

I tried my script in all the places such as in head, in body, at the end but nothing works. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, add a new node in the DOM instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> document.write

That method will overwrite the whole content of your page.
Uses instead a selector to target your HTML node:

> document.querySelector("selector").innerText = "Hello "+logonName:

Or by jQuery:

> $("selector").text("Hello "+logonName);

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
document.write
```

use

```
document.getElementById("usershow").innerHTML = loginName;

<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div id="usershow">user<div>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi @andy , Is the above answer is not solved your issue? he provides you the key solution so why you don't accept it?